# Problem with Authentication chapter and the 19-auth sample

Tags: nestjs

I downloaded the 19-auth sample and add some console.log debug code to it, then found some problems.

The code in JwtAuthGuard is never executed: '2222222' was not printed to the console in the code below:

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
console.log('22222222222');
// add your custom authentication logic here
// for example, call super.logIn(request) to establish a session.
return super.canActivate(context);
}
```

When I changed the guard to JwtAuthGuard in the AuthController:

```
@get('data')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
findAll(@Req() req) {
return req.user;
// this route is restricted by AuthGuard
// JWT strategy
}
```

the code in JwtAuthGuard was invoked, but in the canActivate function, I can't get the user info from request. and the canActivate function was called before the JwtStrategy?

Can someone explain how the code executing for the auth module, and how to get the user info in the JwtAuthGuard?

paste the latest code and console log here:

> JwtStrategy

```
/**
   * jwt passport 调用validate方法来判断是否授权用户进行接口调用
   * @param payload
   */
  async validate(payload: AuthPayload) {
    Logger.log(`payload is ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`, 'JwtStrategy');
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload.id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('不存在的用户信息');
    }
    return user;
  }
```

> JwtAuthGuard

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // add your custom authentication logic here
    // for example, call super.logIn(request) to establish a session.
    // this.accessPriv = this.reflector.get<string>('accessPriv', context.getHandler());
    console.log('canActivate executed 111111111111111111');
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
```

and the console log as below:

```
canActivate executed 111111111111111111

[Nest] 14080   - 2019-04-01 11:19   [JwtStrategy] payload is {"userName":"fanliang","id":"1","iat":1553772641,"exp":1554377441} +2286ms
it seems that the canActivate() function of JwtAuthGuard executed before the validate() function of JwtStrategy, but the user info was attached to the request after JwtStrategy validate().
```

what I want is to get the user info from request in the canActivate() of custom AuthGuard such like JwtAuthGuard

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat solution that works for me.
Calling the super.canActivate before my own logic.
seems like the population of req.user triggered by it.
An example:

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Request } from "express";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardWithAllowSentry extends AuthGuard("jwt") {
  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // that code will call the passport jwt
    const origCanActivate = await super.canActivate(context);
    // now we have request.user!


    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = http.getRequest<Request>();

    console.log(request.user)

    if (request.header("X-Sentry-Token") === "blablabla") {
      if (request.method === "GET" && request.path.endsWith(".map")) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // some random logic
    return request.user.roles.includes("admin")
  }
}
```

it feels for me more like a workaround than a real thing.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that the `19-auth` sample is a little bit confusing to follow. This is mainly because it includes the `JWTAuthGuard` (as a reference for building custom guards) but it is never actually used. Instead, the original use of plain `AuthGuard` is already set up to provide JWT functionality. However, *both* guards leverage the `JWTStrategy`. If you want to understand this better, you could try updating your `AuthController`:

```
  @Get('data')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  findAll() {
    // this route is restricted by AuthGuard
    // JWT strategy
    return {
      message: 'Successfully passed AuthGuard',
    };
  }

  @Get('custom-jwt')
  @UseGuards(new JwtAuthGuard())
  // this route is restricted by JWTAuthGuard custom
  // JWT strategy
  customJwt() {
    return {
      message: 'Successfully passed JWTAuthGuard',
    };
  }
```

The important part is that in order to get past either guard, you must send the request with the Authorization header properly set to the token that's returned from the `token` endpoint.

For example: `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAZW1haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU0MDUyNDczLCJleHAiOjE1NTQwNTYwNzN9.3Q8_FC-qFXk1F4KmMrHVSmmNGPAyHdt2myr5c18_E-U`

I find it easiest to use a tool like Postman or Insomnia for constructing requests and setting Headers, etc but you could also use CURL. Once you've set the `Authorization` header with a valid token you'll be able to hit *both* of the guarded endpoints. If you put a `console.log` in the JWTStrategy you'll see that both guards end up using the `validate` method to retrieve the user correctly.

Comment: I updated the code as you suggested, but I still can't get the user info from request in function canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) of JwtAuthGuard.